# Regular expression pattern for string length 10 which allows special characters also

Tags: html

I have to validate a textbox which allows only 10 characters string and special characters also(e.g. Boot.js, image.jpeg)

I have used following pattern but its not allowing boot.js,image.jpeg text.

```
<input class="k-textbox" data-bind="value:FileName" id="FileName" name="FileName" type="text" value="" pattern="^7.{9}$" title="The field FileName must be a string or array type with a maximum length of '10'">
```

Comment: Try this: "^.{10}$". Might be helpful.

Comment: No,This is also not working.:-(